# How to populate data from json that contains comma separated value into a table in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a json that contains a column name 'status' having multiple comma separated value. I have already populated that json into my table but here problem is I need to put a same background color as coming from json into span. I am not getting here how to do it. Can anyone please help me on it. Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let x of statusdata1;">
            <td style="border:1px solid"><span>{{x.vehicle_number}}</span></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid"><span style="background:{{x.status}}">{{x.status}}</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    imageSource :any;
    statusdata1: any;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.statusdata1 = [{"vehicle_number":1,"status":"red,green"},{"vehicle_number":2,"status":"yellow,red"}];
        console.log(this.statusdata1);
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

**[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rhq3w)** You can send an obj with css attributes to ngStyle

**TS**

```
 data=  [
  {
    "vehicle_number":1,
    "status":"red,green"
    },{
      "vehicle_number":2,
      "status":"yellow,red"
  }];;

  getColor(value) {
   var colors = value.split(',');
    return {
    'background-color': colors[0],
    'color': colors[1]
  };
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of data;">
        <td style="border:1px solid; width:80px" [ngStyle]="getColor(x.status)"><span>{{x.vehicle_number}}</span></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid; width:80px" [ngStyle]="getColor(x.status)">{{x.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

getColor will return to ngStyle

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': yellow, 'color': red}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,here I wanted the same background as status value to each value which is comma separated

Comment: i don't get you. Give me an example

Answer (score -1):

I have added the answer,I have resolved it and this is how I wanted to do.
Here is the demo url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o6epjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### home.comoponent.html

```
<div>
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let x of statusdata1;">
            <td style="border:1px solid"><span>{{x.vehicle_number}}</span></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid"><span [innerHtml]="getTreatment(x.status)"></span></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
imageSource :any;
statusdata1: any;

constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    /* First data */
    this.statusdata1 = [{"vehicle_number":1,"status":"red,green"},{"vehicle_number":2,"status":"yellow,red"}];
    console.log(this.statusdata1);
  }
  getTreatment(data) {
    let str = '<div class="demooutput">'
    let arr = data.split(',');
    if (arr.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        str += '<span class="' + arr[i] + '"><img src="/app/animate/' + arr[i] +  '.png"/></span>'
      }
    }
    str += '</div>'
    return str
  }
}
```